Modifying Li-po and NiMH batteries
I have three 2s 7.4V LiPo batteries, two balance LiPo chargers that can charge 7.4V/11.1V 1s-3s batteries, and soldering tools lying around, so I'm wondering: Can I convert the three 2s 7.4V batteries into two 3s 11.1V batteries by soldering them into a series connection permanently? This would make them resemble the store-sold 3s 11.1V LiPo batteries. This means I would charge and discharge them all together. Would this theoretically work without any problems? Or should I just create additional wires to discharge them in series when using them and charge them separately? Why or why not?
Also, I have two NiMH (6*sc3000mAh 7.2V) batteries that don't have enough voltage, so I want to connect them in series. Should I permanently connect two identical batteries together to charge and discharge in series, or should I also create extra series wires to use only when discharging? Why or why not?

It seems you don't have just batteries but a battery pack. If the packs have a BMS for 2S pack, how would you add a cell to a 2S BMS? Or are they just really cells in series without a BMS?

i believe there is no BMS after I peel the plastic off, unless they are super small and thin hiding between te batteries layers, but I have dead 11.1v lipo batteries I can use their BMS (all the same company, those dead 11.1v lipos are two 3s 11.1V). And for the NIMHs, no BMS only batteries packs
